# Swift error: Binary operator == cannot be applied to type '_' and 'Int'

Tags: swift

I'm brand new to Swift and I'm toying around trying to build a simple program that will tell the user what year of the Chinese calendar they were born in based on their age.

```
    var string1 = "You are year of the"
    let age:Int? = Int(ageField.text!)

    if age <= 12 {
        let remainder = age!
    } else {
        let remainder = age! % 12
    }

    if remainder == 0 {
        string1 += " sheep."
    }; if remainder == 1 {
        string1 += " horse."
    }; if remainder == 2 {
        string1 += " snake."
    }; if remainder == 3 { // And so on and so forth...
```

I get an error message on each "if" line that says the binary operator '==' cannot be applied to the operands of type '_' and 'Int'. Any ideas what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Assuming that `age <= 12` should actually be `age < 12` (in order to get a remainder between 0 and 11), there is no need to test this at all. Just `let remainder = age! % 12`.

Comment: You need to test for `age` being `nil`. `let age:Int = Int(ageField.text!)` where `ageField.text` == "Grimxn" will cause your later assignments to crash (once they compile) - see @AlessandroChiarotto's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variable/constants `remainder` should be declared outside the `if` construct and also you can remove the character ";" in your code. Swift does not need ";" at the end of instruction like objective-c

Answer (score 2):

As a summary of Alessandro's answer and the comments your optimized code could look like

```
var string1 = "You are year of the"
if let age = Int(ageField.text!) {

    let remainder = age % 12

    if remainder == 0 {
        string1 += " sheep."
    } else if remainder == 1 {
        string1 += " horse."
    } else if remainder == 2 {
        string1 += " snake."
    } // And so on and so forth...

} else {
    print("please enter a number")
}
```

or a bit "swiftier" using a `switch` statement

```
var string1 = "You are year of the "
if let age = Int(ageField.text!) {

    switch age % 12 {

    case 0: string1 += "sheep."
    case 1: string1 += "horse."
    case 2: string1 += "snake."
        // And so on and so forth...
    }

} else {
    print("please enter a number")
}
```

PS: actually the sheep is a goat ;-)